# comparing two Chi-Squared distributions

Tags: probability, chi-squared

I am looking at a paper that is interested in finding a probability that one chi-squared variable is smaller than another.

More precisely

$$
\Pr\left[\sum_{i=1}^k\left(X_i-Y_i+Z_i\right)^2\leq \sum_{i=1}^k\left(Z_i\right)^2\right]
\\ X,Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2) \text{ and } Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)
$$
and all three RV are independent.

the paper states that
that this probability is

$$
= 1-\mathrm{E}_\theta\left\{\mathcal{Q}_{k/2}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\theta}{2\sigma^2}},
\sqrt{\frac{\theta}{2\sigma^2}}\right)\right\} 
$$

Where $\mathcal{Q}$ is the Marcum Q Function and $\theta\sim\chi_k^2$.

Running trials this does seem to be correct, but I don't know enough about the Marcum Q function to see how they derived this.

I am guessing this is related to the Marcum Q expression for the CDF of a non central chi-square distribution.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

---

Update I think I figured out the broad strokes.... if we work through the equation then we get something like
$$
\Pr\left[\sum_{i=1}^k\left(X_i^2 +Y_i^2+Z_i^2-2X_iY_i+2X_iN_i-2Y_iN_i\right)\leq \sum_{i=1}^k\left(Z_i\right)^2\right]
\Pr\left[\sum_{i=1}^k-\left(X_i^2 -2X_iY_i+2X_iN_i-2Y_iN_i\right)\geq \sum_{i=1}^k\left(Y_i\right)^2\right]
$$

which seems to make some sense as we take the expectation over all possible $Y$ we get the integration limit in $\mathcal{Q}$.  I will have to see if I can coax the left side to be a non-central chi-squared distribution with the correct $\lambda$ non-centrality parameter as it's evaluated for fixed Y_i.

Comment: What's $\theta$?

Comment: Thanks for the note.  It's an independent central chi squared distributed random variable with k degrees of freedom.  I will update the question.